# Online tool for low bandwidth simulation?

Tags: browser, pagespeed

I'm looking for an online tool that will allow me to enter a URL and a connection speed (56k, DSL, cable modem, etc) in order to test the performance of a web site under various speeds.

Any help much appreciated. I've tried sloppy (does not work for me behind firewall), and "Firefox Throttle" (not compatible with the latest version of Firefox).

I'm testing from a Windows 7 based PC.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://www.ngcoders.com/downloads/internet-speed-simulator-proxy-throttler/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be an online tool you can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to simulate modem speed for example. [This guide](http://mrentropy.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-fiddler-to-simulate-dsl-speeds.html) shows how to set up the speed you wish to test for.

Answer (score 0):

there is a more up to date blogpost on the fiddler technique: http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/simulating-a-slow-connection-with-fiddler